# webfonts: @font-face should include font-style and font-weight?

Tags: css, fonts, font-face, webfonts, google-webfonts

When including a `@font-face` and `src` to import a webfont, I notice you can pass in 2 optional values. I am not doing that presently.

I have 2 Web-fonts, Lato Regular and Lato Bold.

Should I be specifying weight in the `@font-face` rule?

It says by default it uses regular.

I am not passing anything and it seems to render correctly i.e the bold version seems to be bold.

Would love to know the recommended way of doing this and what advantages or disadvantages it has?

Passing in bold as a weight would force the browser to bold the font? But its already bold - right?

Comment: Please post your CSS code.

Comment: Isn't this a bit primarily opinion-based? Or am I mistaken?

Comment: Not OP, but think it should *not* be opinion-based. The original author of a font face is the person designating slant and boldness of each variant they design, and random people on Internet (including embedding users) should not make uninformed decisions whether the font face they are importing "looks" "regular" or "bold", or what kind of slant it resembles. Also, the information about the kind of detail is embedded in the font face, so technically the user agent could infer it better than by *user* specification. Regardless, the explicit specification should follow author intent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should. The `font-weight` and `font-style` specify what you consider the font face to be. This means that you can embed a what is designed by an author to be a regular font face, as a bold font face. This also means that when you use such font face, you'd better use `font-weight: bold`, unless there are no alternatives in which case the user agent will select the font face anyway.

In your case:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: /* The URL of the resource containing the non-slanted regular font face. */
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "Lato";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: bold; /* or 700 */
    src: /* The URL of the resource containing the non-slanted font face with 'bold'/700 glyphs. */
}
```

If you don't specify `font-weight` in your `@font-face` rule, your font face is assumed by user agent to have glyphs with the default weight of 400 ("regular"). Consequently, not specifying `font-weight` in rules that reference your font face, still defaults to same font weight, and everything is fine, there is no conflict.

I also frequently use numeric font weights, because all too often custom fonts are divided into semi-bold and extra-bold gradations, so having something like `font-weight: 600` lets you select an embedded semi-bold font face (which also has `font-weight: 600` in its corresponding `@font-face` rule).